# PHP foreach in special array

Tags: php

I need some help to loop through all the values in one nested array. I need to recovery the id into array, and the ID from parent array. The first level must be a parent_id = 0, the orders are the id from the parent array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => 3
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 13
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 48
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 52
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 61
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 54
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 55
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 56
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I'm using the following PHP script to recovery the data:

```
function readClass($k, $v, &$parent_id, &$new_id, &$order_id ) {

    $out = "";

    if (!is_array($v)) {

        $out .= "<li>id:$v | parent_id:$parent_id | order:$order_id ";

        if (($parent_id == "0") || ($new_id == "S")) { 
            $parent_id = $v; 
            $new_id = 'N';
        }

    } else {

        foreach($v as $k2=>$v2) {
            $order_id++;
            $out .= readClass($k2, $v2, $parent_id, $new_id, $order_id);
        }
    }

    return $out;    
}   


foreach($someArray as $key=>$value) {
    $parent_id = '0';
    $order_id = '0';
    $new_id = 'N';
    echo readClass($key, $value, $parent_id, $new_id, $order_id );
}
```

And the results are:

```
id:3 | parent_id:0 | order:1 
id:13 | parent_id:3 | order:4 
id:48 | parent_id:3 | order:6   
id:52 | parent_id:3 | order:9
id:61 | parent_id:3 | order:11
id:10 | parent_id:0 | order:1
id:54 | parent_id:10 | order:4
id:55 | parent_id:10 | order:7
id:56 | parent_id:10 | order:10
```

and i want to recover like this:

```
id:3 | parent_id:0 | order:1 
id:13 | parent_id:3 | order:4 
id:48 | parent_id:3 | order:6   
id:52 | parent_id:48 | order:9
id:61 | parent_id:48 | order:11
id:10 | parent_id:0 | order:1
id:54 | parent_id:10 | order:4
id:55 | parent_id:54 | order:7
id:56 | parent_id:55 | order:10
```

Note the diference in parent_id's from id's (52,61,55,56). It's the problem...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't use the first parameter, I've removed that and re-organised the code quite a bit.  The idea being that you fetch the from the element and output the current item.  Then if there are elements in children, then pass this ID into the recursive call and process each of the sub-elements...

```
function readClass( $v, $parent_id, &$new_id, &$order_id ) {
    $out = "";
    $order_id++;
    $out .= "<li>id:$v[id] | parent_id:$parent_id | order:$order_id ";
    if ( isset($v["children"]) )  {
        $parent_id = $v["id"];
        foreach ( $v["children"] as $children ) {
            $out .= readClass( $children, $parent_id, $new_id, $order_id);
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

foreach($someArray as $key=>$value) {
    $parent_id = '0';
    $order_id = '0';
    $new_id = 'N';
    echo readClass($value, $parent_id, $new_id, $order_id );
}
```

I've tried to test this with a subset of your data and it seems to generate it OK, but you will have to check it and let me know if there are specific errors.

Comment: it's run fine. I need to put the $order_id = 0 out of first foreach to increment the order in arrays with no sub-itens.

Comment: If you move the line `$order_id++;` to after the `$out .= "<...` line it will put 0 for the first order ID.

Answer (score 0):

I did things a little differently. I don't know what the purpose of new_id is, but I don't think it's being used in your code.

You are iterating each item in the array instead of knowing the structure and working around that.

The following snippet just iterates each item and continues down so long as it has children, updating the parentId.

```php
function readClass($arr,$parentId = 0,&$order = 0){
    echo $arr['id'] . ', ' . $parentId . ', ' . $order . "\n";
    if(isset($arr['children'])){
        foreach($arr['children'] as $child){
            $order++;
            readClass($child,$arr['id'],$order);
        }
    }
}
```

Order won't be the same as yours, though.

Comment: i have some problem with order variable in tests of multi-levels (3 or more sub levels). The @Nigel Ren code runs at various options with a little change.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the folling problem: You were never sending a new `$parent_id`. So i made a change on the `readClass` function:

```
function readClass($k, $v, &$parent_id, &$new_id, &$order_id ) {

    $out = "";

    if (!is_array($v)) {

        $out .= "<li>id:$v | parent_id:$parent_id | order:$order_id ";

        if (($parent_id == "0") || ($new_id == "S")) {
            $parent_id = $v;
            $new_id = 'N';
        }

    } else {
        $old_value2 = 0;
        foreach($v as $k2=>$v2) {
            if($k2 === "children")  // -- If the current index is children(They will need a new father)
                $parent_id = $old_value2;
            $order_id++;
            $out .= readClass($k2, $v2, $parent_id, $new_id, $order_id);
            $old_value2 = $v2; // -- We always set the old one as the new father in case he has childrens 
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: This response runs ok too, with the change of '$order_id = 0' out of first foreach. I'm using the response from @nigel-ren because the code it's shorter.